# How to reference content in a frame in new window with PowerShell?

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer, powershell, frames

I'm using PowerShell to login to a web app.  Upon logging in, the app opens a new window.  The new window has a frameset with three frames.  I'm trying to click a link in one of the frames ("Left").

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://example.local")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 }
$ie.visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document

$userField = $doc.getElementById("uid")
$passwordField = $doc.getElementById("pwd")
$submitButton = $doc.getElementById("submit")

$userField.value = "userid"
$passwordField.value = "*****"
$submitButton.click()

$shell = New-object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
# The app opens a new window with a timestamp - that's the window I want, so I skip the other window
$ie2 = $shell.Windows() | where {$_.Type -eq "HTML Document" -and $_.LocationName -ne "My App - Parent Window"}
$doc2 = $ie2.document
$frames = @($doc2.getElementsByTagName("FRAME"))
Write-Host $frames.Count # shows "3"
Write-Host $frames[1].Title # shows "Left Nav"
```

How do I reference the Left frame?  I've tried various combinations that I thought would work, mostly some variation of `$frames[1].document.something...`.

The HTML (not my code):

```
<frameset rows="60,*">
    <frame src="http://example.local/really/long?url" title="Top Nav" name="Top" id="Top">
    <frameset cols="175,*">
        <frame src="http://example.local/left.html" title="Left Nav" name="Left" id="Left">
        <frame src="http://example.local/main.html" title="Main Display" name="Main" id="Main">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Instead of using the $frames array, I used the frames property as suggested by @Adi.

```
$frames = $doc2.frames
$left = $frames.item([ref]1).document      # the frame I need
$left_frames = $left.frames                # this page has frames too
$nav = $left_frames.item([ref]0).document  # the frame I need
$nav.body.outerHTML                        # gives me the code I need
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reading the frames into an array of elements by invoking the Document object's **GetElementsByTagName()** method, use the Document object's **frames** property, which will return an object specialized for interacting with frames:

```powershell
$frames = $ie2.document.frames
```

This returns an object representing all the frames. To reference individual frames, `$frames[1]` isn't going to work because **$frames** is not a collection, so you can't index into it. It's a ComObject, and ComObjects that represent a grouping of the same type of item typically have an **Item** method for referencing individual items in that group, by specifying an index number as an argument. Examining the available properties and methods with `$frames | gm`, you can see that there is in fact an **item** method.

I'm not sure exactly how the index numbers are assigned to frames, but presumably it's some sort of left-to-right, then top-to-bottom scheme, so if you have a top, left, and right frame, it's a safe bet that the index number will be 1. Try this:

```powershell
$frames.item(1).document.something...
```

Comment: `$frames.item(0).document` gives me `Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] doesn't contain a method named 'item'.`

`$frames.item[0].document` gives me `Cannot index into a null array.`

Comment: Actually, on a closer look, I see that the way you're defining **$frames**, it *is* an array, because you're forcing the issue with the `@`. Not only should you not do that, don't bother with **GetElementsByTagName()** either, that just complicates things; **frames** is a property of the document object. So, define it this way: `$frames = $ie2.document.frames`.

Comment: `$doc2 = $ie2.document`  
`$doc2.frames.length` gives  
3  
`$doc2.frames.item(0)` gives
Argument: '1' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].

Comment: Okay, I looked up "[ref]", and changed my code to `$doc2.frames.item([ref]1).document.body.innerHTMl`.  Not yet sure if it's exactly what I want, but it's not an error!

Comment: That's odd. The **item** method should take an integer (the index of the object in the object collection), not a reference. Unfortunately, I'm quite sure that this does *not* give you what you want, because `[ref]1` is meaningless. `[ref]$var` gets the reference of **$var** (as opposed to its value). For example, if you assign `$tom = [ref]$cat`, and then change the value of **$cat**, the value of **$tom** changes as well, because it points to the same memory location.

Comment: I really don't see how you'd be getting that error from the **item** method. I tested this the same way you're doing it, navigating to a web page that opens a new window when you click a button, then retrieving that new window by filtering a Shell.Application object for the window's title, then `document.frames.item(0)` on the returned object, and and it works fine. I had a thought, that because you're searching by what the window title is *not* rather than what it is, maybe you have other browser windows open, and $ie2 is an *array* of ComObjects.

Comment: However, that still wouldn't explain the error. In PSv3+, if **ie2** is an array of IE windows, then `$ie2.document.frames.item(0)` returns the first frame of the first window in the array, and in earlier versions you'd just get a "cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error. Is the web page you're working with publicly accessible?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a public page.  And to add to the hilarity, it appears that there are additional i/frames inside the frame I thought I wanted.  Ultimately, I wanted to click a link, but it appears that the "navigation" menu is created dynamically with javascript.  Not sure how to proceed here.  SO wants us to move this to chat....